# Sorting a Range based on sheet variable with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**Scenario:** I have a sheet and am trying to sort a part of it. Inside the sheet I have a dropdown list, which allows me to select the values (aaa, bbb, ccc). Each of those values represent a column and when selected, the code should sort the range by that column.

**Problem:** The process works for one of the values in the dropdown list, but not for the others (it runs, but nothing happens).

**Code:**

```
Sub ratecolumnssort()

    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim sortColumn As String, sortAgent As String

    shtMonitoring.Activate
    LastRow = shtMonitoring.Cells(shtMonitoring.rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row

    sortAgent = shtMonitoring.Cells(8, 9) ' this is where the dropdown with values aaa, bbb and ccc is

    If sortAgent = "aaa" Then
        sortColumn = "F"
    ElseIf sortAgent = "bbb" Then
        sortColumn = "H"
    ElseIf sortAgent = "ccc" Then
        sortColumn = "J"
    End If

    With ActiveSheet.sort
        .SortFields.Add key:=Range(sortColumn & "11"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange Range("B11", "N" & LastRow )
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

**Question:** What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: **Not tested**, but I think that every sorting needs a previous clearing. Try something lke `ActiveSheet..AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear` before each sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the sort settings first.

```
 With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear 'add this line
        'as before
```